# How can I turn this into a function in R with a df name and column name?

Tags: r, function, nas

I am struggling to make a function accepting a df and column that will replace NAs with median all summarized by three different columns. I need to make this repeatable across eight columns.

Comment: Hi Katie!  Welcome to SO!  I think you may want to try the `na_if` function from dplyr.  You can see examples here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/na_if.html . In the future, it will be helpful to include a reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What I have in the first code above works perfectly fine and gives me the results I need. I just don't want to have to create that 8 times over for each column, so I was hoping to simplify with a function.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [Tidy evaluation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).

#### Quick Fix

It looks like you're replacing missing values with the median value of the state/year group, so I wrote a function that will do that.

```r
replace_na_median <- function(df, col) {
  new_df <- df %>% 
    group_by(State, Year) %>% 
    mutate(
      "{{col}}" := ifelse(is.na({{col}}), median({{col}}, na.rm = TRUE), {{col}})
    )
  
  return(new_df)
}
```

Note that this returns a new df. To use it iteratively across a few columns, you have to assign each time.

```r
monthlySummary <- monthlySummary %>%
    replace_na_median(col1) %>%
    replace_na_median(col2) %>%
    ...
```

And so on.

#### There's a better way

To replace all NAs in a set of columns with a year/state grouped median, you can use `dplyr::across`. No intermediate functions, and you don't have to specify each column individually (you use Tidy select).

```r
# Replace all NAs in cols a, b, and c with year/state median
df %>% 
  group_by(State, Year) %>%
  mutate(
    across(a:c, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), median(x, na.rm = TRUE), x))
  )
```

#### Notes

Tidy evaluation isn't a small topic, and the link at the top will do a much better job than I could explaining it. It's fairly easy to make quick-fixes, though. There are some other things I'd like to point out about your code.

- You don't have to remove variables that are defined within a function. They are automatically removed once the function ends.
- You don't need to summarize and then merge to get the median for a group. Simply group and use `mutate` like in the code above.
- It's not clear what to do when a state/year combination is *all* `NA` values. When this occurs, in the code above, the values remain `NA`.
- A variable name is not a character string. Your line `a <- paste(col, "Median")` will create a vector (of length `length(col)`) in which every *value* of `col` is suffixed with `"Median"`. It seems your intention was to create a single string to use as a variable name. To do this, you can use `deparse(substitute(col))`, which takes whatever is passed as `col` and converts it to a character string. e.g.

```r
basic_func <- function(whatsthis) {
  itsthis <- deparse(substitute(whatsthis))
  cat(itsthis)
}

basic_func(helloworld)
## "helloworld"

basic_func(this_column)
## "this_column"
```

Comment: The "there's a better way" worked perfectly and was extremely fast. Thank you!

Comment: Nice answer! I'd suggest further improvement to "there's a better way", `across(a:c, ~ replace_na(., median(., na.rm = TRUE)))`

Comment: Glad to help! If this fully answers your question, you can accept it as the answer